# Convert P2SH to P2PKH

Tags: wallet-recovery, p2sh, p2pkh

I'm using [btcrecover](https://github.com/gurnec/btcrecover) to recover a Ledger BIP39 backup seed that I wrote down but seems to be wrong. The tool only accepts P2PKH addresses and my account was created very recently in this kind of format `3J98t1WpEZ73CNmQviecrnyiWrnqRhWNLy`. I'm new to blockchain but I believe that this is a Segwit/P2SH account?

Is there a way I can convert this into a P2PKH address so that I can use the tool?

Comment: Which software did you create the wallet or address with?

Comment: It was on a Ledger Nano S

Comment: What is it that makes you believe that the seed you wrote down is incorrect? (i.e. missing bitcoin?)

Comment: The device erased all private and public keys after 3 unsuccessful attempts to enter a pin and now says the seed is invalid when trying to recover the data

Comment: If you haven't sent any bitcoin to the addresses generated from your old seed, consider starting a fresh and generating a new seed.

Comment: Unfortunately I have BTC on the account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting address formats is not feasible without knowing the public or private key(s) used to generate them.

Without reviewing the source code of btcrecover, I can't advise whether you should use it or not. But if you do trust it and decide to use it, consider first generating a new seed and address to immediately send your bitcoin to.

Consider any seed you may recover with btcrecover compromised and no longer secure.